# How to make my own syntactic sugar in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out how to define a Swift type with the use of syntactic sugar. Like apple has given to the Array struct the ability to define it both ways: `Array​<​String​>` and `[​String​]`, how can I do the same for MyStruct?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Would defining a struct two ways add much?

Comment: I am trying to define my own syntactic sugar like apple do with the Array struct, I believe that Swift gives me that functionality. Mostly I am doing it in order to better understand the language architecture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You kind of can and can’t do this.

You cannot define a type with a shorthand like `[String]`.  You can’t, for example, define a new linked list and give it the a shorthand of `‹String›`.

What you *can* do is implement `ArrayLiteralConvertible`, so that you can create your list like this:

```
let mylist: List = ["Elsa","Anna"]
```

by implementing `ArrayLiteralConvertible`:

```
struct List<T> {
  // your List implementation
}

extension List: ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    init(arrayLiteral: T...) {
        // populate list from from arrayLiteral
    }
}
```

`Set` is an example of a type that does this.  Arrays are the default, but you can create sets with `let myset: Set = [1,2,3]`.

Likewise you can implement `StringLiteralConvertible` (`let r: Regex = "^abc.*def$"`), but you can’t create a shorthand `let r = /^abc.*def$/`, only the language designers can do that.

Comment: And tell him about defining his own operators.

Comment: true enough, there is enough raw syntactic sugar out there to give anyone dietary problems...

Comment: What I want to say is that Array is not part of swift language, but is part of the swift standard library. So the swift language give the ability to the swift standard library to make a struct call it Array<T> and then also give it the ability of sugar initialization. So if the swift lets the standard library do it, it should also let anyone else do it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yup.  While the Swift standard library is mostly implemented in Swift and you can reproduce much of what it does yourself, there are a few special things it does that you can’t – for example, you can implement your own optional type using enums, but you wouldn’t write the optional chaining operator or the implicit up conversion of non-optionals to optionals.  Those kind of things are hard-coded into Swift and not achievable by us mortal users.