# What's the difference between Array<T> and [T]?

Tags: arrays, swift

Title says it all.  I'm expecting an array to be handed to me via an `Any?` parameter (don't ask! I hate they implemented it like that!), and I want to test if that's what I actually got.  Not sure if I should be testing for `Array<T>` or `[T]` or if there's even a difference.

Comment: AFAIK `[T]` is the array literal version of `Array<T>`. So basically no difference. See documentation from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

Comment: But you can also define a variable as `var x:[Int]` so it's definitely a data type, not just a literal. But of course you can also do `var x:Array<Int>`

Comment: It's all syntactic sugar, there is no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others already explained in the comments there is no difference.

Both `Array<T>` and `[T]` definitions means: **A generic array of type T**.

### Defining a type

Swift provides 4 main syntactic sugars to **define a type**, here's the list.

### 1. An Optional `Int`

```
let optionalInt: Optional<Int>
```

is equivalent to

```
let optionalInt: Int?
```

### 2. An Implicitly Unwrapped Optional `Int`

```
let implicitlyUnwrappedInt: ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>
```

is equivalent to

```
let implicitlyUnwrappedInt: Int!
```

### 3. An Array of `Int(s)`

```
let nums: [Int]
```

is equivalent to

```
let nums: Array<Int>
```

### 4. A Dictionary where the `Key` is `String` and the `Value` is `Int`

```
let dict: [String:Int]
```

is equivalent to

```
let dict: Dictionary<String:Int>
```

### Conclusion

You can find more info on [this page of The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html).

> Finally, if you are wondering [How to make your own syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527421/how-to-make-my-own-syntactic-sugar-in-swift), you can't

Comment: Nice. *The `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` type is deprecated. To create an optional value that is implicitly unwrapped, place an exclamation mark (`!`) after the type that you want to denote as optional.* From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/implicitlyunwrappedoptional).